# How to get a method to detect 'remote_form_for' usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

New to Rails... here goes:

If I want my 'create' method to respond differently to an AJAX request than to a normal POST request, can I have the method detect which was used?

Or, is it better to use different methods for AJAX and non-AJAX requests?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternately, you can use a respond_to block:

```
def create
  # ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # for standard requests
    format.js # for AJAX requests
    # other formats...
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work if you're returning HTML with your AJAX request.

Answer (score 3):

request.xhr?